# Play Sound In Meteor-Cordova App

Tags: cordova, meteor

Using meteor without cordova I can play a sound fine in my browser using

```
 new Audio('test.mp3').play()
```

where `test.mp3` is located in the public folder. However I cannot play the sound once I run my app as a cordova app on a device. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try: `new Audio('/test.mp3').play()`?

Comment: @stubailo I Did do that.

Comment: Did you happen to find anything that didn't require another request (http)?

Comment: @jimmiebtlr I have not found a really good solution. What about you?

Comment: Not yet, looking at the media plugin source didn't help me much either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr

1. Install cordova media plugin `meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.media@0.2.15`
2. Add audio files to public directory
3. Use `/android_asset/www/application/path/to/sound.wav`

If you look inside this folder in your project,

`$PROJECT_ROOT/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/assets/www/`

You will see your application as cordova built it for android.

Using the Cordova Media plugin, I attempted to use the file path `/android_asset/www/path/to/sound.wav` to no avail.

```
# Install the cordova media plugin with this command
meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.media@0.2.15
```

Instead, I saw that my sounds folder was inside the www directory but under an application directory. So, this file path ended up working for me,

`/android_asset/www/application/path/to/sound.wav`

Here's the relevant code that worked for me.

```
function getMediaUrl(sound) {

  if (device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") {

    return cordova.file.applicationDirectory.replace('file://', '') + 'www/application/' + sound.substr(1);

  }
  else {

    return cordova.file.applicationDirectory.replace('file://', '') + sound.substr(1);

  }

}

function playSound(sound) {

  return new Media(

    getMediaUrl(sound),

    function (success) {
      // success
    },
    function (err) {
      // error
    }
  );
}

var test = playSound('/sounds/test.wav');

test.play();
```

**NOTE**: I included my audio files in the public folder i.e.

`$PROJECT_ROOT/public/sounds/test.wav`

and on Android, this file path is translated to

`/android_asset/www/application/sounds/test.wav`

Comment: For iOS, I had to use this: `return cordova.file.applicationDirectory.replace('file://', '') + 'www/application/' + sound.substr(1);` So that part is not just for android.

Comment: ^ Yeah they are both the same.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I used `cdvfile://` instead of `file://`... and `www/application/app/` instead of `www/application/`.

Comment: I simply cannot get it to work on iOS. @Yong: Did you REPLACE cdvfile:// with an empty string or did you actually add cdvfile:// to the path? Can somebody please just write a complete path?

Comment: @Pueggel here is the function I used 
```
function getMediaUrl(sound) {
 if (device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") {
  return cordova.file.applicationDirectory
  .replace('cdvfile://', '') + 'www/application/app/' + sound.substr(1);
 }
 else {
  return cordova.file.applicationDirectory
  .replace('cdvfile://', '') + sound.substr(1);
 }
}

getMediaUrl('/sounds/music_name.mp3')
```

Comment: I can not get this to work. My local URL seems to be slightly different, but I also can't get audio to play that's served from the web. It just fails silently.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be two possible solutions. The first which is probably the more correct solution is only valid for cordova apps. It will not work in the browser due to the plugin dependency. First step is to add the cordova plugin:

```
  meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.media@0.2.15
```

Next build a function to play the sound:

```
playLimitSound = function() {
  if (Meteor.isCordova) {
        var my_media = new Media('http://MY_IP:port/test.mp3',
            // success callback
            function () {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
            },
            // error callback
            function (err) {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
            }
        );
        // Play audio
        my_media.play();
}
```

};

This is another solution. It works both in browser and cordova-app.

```
 new Audio('http://MY_IP:port/test.mp3').play()
```

Comment: This won't be as good on Cordova because then it will load the sound from the web server instead of from the local device.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with iOS push notification sound. It was solved when I add sound files to Resources folder in Xcode before Xcode compile the app. In this case you can refer to it as:

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
  var NotificationHandler = function(evt) {
    if (evt.sound) {
      var snd = new Media( 
        Meteor.absoluteUrl(evt.sound), 
        function() { console.log('media ok'); }, 
        function(err) { console.log('media error',err); }
      );
      snd.play();
    }
  };
}
```

where evt.sound is for example 'test.mp3'

and I had media plugin installed as

```
 meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.media@0.2.14
```

Comment: In the example code you use absoluteUrl which resolves to `http://URL:PORT/resource_location`

When you say add it to the resource folder, what exact path are we talking about?  Something like `public/resources/sound.wav`?

Comment: the path is in your cordoba build, not in public directory of Meteor project. for iOS the best way is just drag and drop them into Xcode Resource directory of your project. Then Xcode add them as resources (the same way icons and splash are added)...

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to play the sound locally (no internet connection) then you need to change your host address to:

```
http://meteor.local/[your_subfolder(s)_if_you_got]/your.mp3
```

With this URL you can of course do the mentioned Media or Audio calls. If your assets are in public folder or the resources folder then you can always assume this URL as per design these files are copied into your app bundle.

Comment: Which version of Meteor are you using? With Meteor 1.3 it changed.

Comment: Also doesn't work for me. I'm on Meteor 1.4.something.

Answer (score 1):

I just couldn't get any of the proposed solutions to work on Android, in any way shape or form. My app, on Android, would just silently fail when trying to play sound.

In the end, this is what did work for me:

```
        var player = new window.Audio();

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                player.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
                player.play();
            }
        };
        xhr.open('GET', "/audio.mp3");
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.send();
```

From [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/cordova-playing-audio-file-from-public/28887/4?u=mastababa).