# Play local audio in meteor cordova app

Tags: cordova, audio, meteor

I would like to play a file `sound.mp3` in cordova which is in the `/public` folder of my meteor app. In the console, I can see that the file is being downloaded:

```
METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /sound.mp3
```

The following does not work anymore:

```
var getLocalPath = function (localPath) {
    return cordova.file.applicationDirectory.replace('file://', '') + 'www/application/' + localPath.substr(1);
};
var src = getLocalPath('/sound.mp3');
var media = new Media(src).play();
```

I could, of course, access the sound from the server and play it through a regular Audio object, but that is an unnecessary detour. And since my app should runs offline, this is not an option for me. However, for the record, the following does actually work in cordova:

```
new Audio(Meteor.absoluteUrl('sound.mp3')).play()
```

(Meteor.absoluteUrl returns the server Url)

Comment: does `new Media('/sound.mp3').play();` not work? If the file is indeed in the `public` folder, then it should.

Comment: It doesn't work. And yes, it is in the public folder. Is there a way to see if the Media object has actually been given a valid path? I mean you can write anything in there and you won't see any errors when calling .play()

Comment: where does this code get executed? did you wait for `deviceready`?

Comment: Waiting for deviceready does not help. No success so far. I am still loading using the files from the server as a workaround...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this for the path to the media file:

```
cordova.file.applicationDirectory.replace('file://', '') + 'www/application/app/' + 'sounds/my.mp3';
```

The hint came from here:
[Play Sound In Meteor-Cordova App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432554/play-sound-in-meteor-cordova-app)