# howler.js and phonegap is not working like a team?

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio, howler.js

I am tryint to use howler.js to play a chain of sounds in a phonegap app. In the mobile browser or even the normal browser this code works fine! but when i compile to an apk or i use phonegap build.. i can not get any sound from howler.js :(

the following code is very basic, it is just for one sound clip but my issue is the same...

```
function load_sound_test() {
// just for set the clip

    var namesoundtest =  "sounds/effects/" + document.getElementById('xsoundtest').value + ".webm";     
    var newnamesound = array_sound_test.push(namesoundtest);
    var namesoundtest =  "sounds/effects/" + document.getElementById('xsoundtest').value + ".mp3";      
    var newnamesound = array_sound_test.push(namesoundtest);
    var namesoundtest =  "sounds/effects/" + document.getElementById('xsoundtest').value + ".wav";      
    var newnamesound = array_sound_test.push(namesoundtest);    

    sound_test = new Howl({
      src: array_sound_test,
      preload: true,
      autoplay: false,
      loop: false,
      buffer: true
    });
console.log("sound test loaded");
}

function play_sound_test() {
// just to play the clip

    sound_test.play()
    console.log("sound test played");

}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: No, nobody help me, my project is stopped. so sorry... :) My project is so nice and funny...

Comment: I also couldn't get audio to play on Android, but found a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44076254/1374538